# PYGame - Changing bullets bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

> First of all, my point is making 3 different bullets with different stats and different colors. Shoot them with Space key, selecting them with 1,2 and 3 keys. I'm not putting whole code here but if you need more info feel free to ask.

```py
    LaserDict = {
        "redLaser": (RED_LASER,4,1),        #Bad Velocity       #Bad Firerate 
        "greenLaser": (GREEN_LASER,10,3),   #Excellent Velocity #Good Firerate   
        "blueLaser": (BLUE_LASER,5,2)       #Medium Velocity    #Good Firerate   
    }
 

    class Lasers():
        def __init__(self,x,y,laserIndex):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.laserNames =  ["redLaser","greenLaser","blueLaser"]
            self.laserIndex = laserIndex
            self.laserImg, self.laserVel, self.laserCooldown = LaserDict[self.laserNames[self.laserIndex]]

        def draw(self,window):
            window.blit(self.laserImg,(self.x,self.y))
        
        def move(self,p):
            self.y += p
    
        def offScreen(self,height):
            return not (self.y>0 and self.y<=height) #if not in screen return True
    
    class Player():
        fpsCooldown = 30
        def __init__(self,x,y,health,laserIndex):
             blah blah...

             self.cooldownReady = 0
             self.lasers = []
             self.laserIndex = laserIndex

        def cooldown(self):
            if self.cooldownReady >= self.fpsCooldown:
                self.cooldownReady = 0
            elif self.cooldownReady > 0:
                self.cooldownReady += Lasers(self.x,self.y,self.laserIndex).laserCooldown
    
        def shoot(self):
            if self.cooldownReady == 0:
                laser = Lasers(self.x+int(self.getWidth()/8) ,self.y, self.laserIndex)
                self.lasers.append(laser)
                self.cooldownReady = 1

        def moveLasers(self):
            self.cooldown()
            for laser in self.lasers:
                p = Lasers(self.x,self.y,self.laserIndex).laserVel
                laser.move(-p)
            
                if laser.offScreen(height):
                    self.lasers.remove(laser)
    def main():
        blah blah...
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            player.shoot()
            
        if keys[pygame.K_1]:
            player.laserIndex = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_2]:
            player.laserIndex = 1
        if keys[pygame.K_3]:
            player.laserIndex = 2
```

> Code is working fine with one bug. When you change your laser type by
> pressing 1,2 or 3 it changes all of your Laser's stats exist in
> window. For example if you shoot "Red Lasers" 5 times and if they are
> not off the screen yet, and if you change your laser type to "GreenLasers" all of your "Red Lasers" remains red but  moving just like
> Green ones.

Comment: Please, post the `Lasers.move` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `moveLasers` you calculate how much to move each laser with the variable `p`. This value `p` is calculated by creating a new `Lasers` with the *current* `player.laserIndex`, meaning that all lasers will move this much. You're better off changing `Lasers.move` to:

```py
def move(self):
    self.y += self.laserVel
```

rather than re-finding `p` everytime, which is only the `laserVel` for the current mode anyway

Comment: Great advice, it worked perfectly. I will share codes too maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for your bullet, with its own stats.
Here, when you modify the bullet stats on the player, it affects all the bullets because you update your bullets inside the Player.
You could also keep a track of every bullet inside the player but it is overwhelming.

In you Bullet Object, just add it a direction, a speed and a color. The update every frame, just check if it reaches the end of the screen to erase it (to not lose memory).

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

> Lasers.move() changed to:

```
def move(self):
    self.y -= self.laserVel

def moveEnemyLasers(self,p):
    self.y += p
```

> Player.moveLasers() changed to:

```
def moveLasers(self):
    self.cooldown()
    for laser in self.lasers:
        laser.move()
        if laser.offScreen(height):
            self.lasers.remove(laser)
```